# How to connect Azure Web Application (App Service/Website) to Network Security Group?

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-web-app-service, network-security-groups

I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple, or if I'm trying to do the impossible.

I have a Tomcat site deployed on Azure using the Web+Mobile App Services model. This is NOT a VM. I would like to be able to apply firewall rules (network security group) to this App Service.

Here is what I have done within my Resource Group:

1. Taken my existing App Service (Tomcat) and upgraded it to S1 machine size.
2. Created a VNET with default settings. This included creating a subnet named "default". All address space suggestions were left at Azure default prompts.
3. Used the Network settings blade on the App Service to select the VNET I just created.
4. Created a Network Security Group - added an incoming rule to deny  HTTP port 80 from ANY source.
5. Associated NSG created above with the default subnet
6. Waited for everything to propogate
7. Tested hitting the App Service on HTTP Port 80, and got results returned.

This was not what I was hoping to see. To debug this I tested:

1. Create a Tomcat Virtual Machine
2. On the VM Network blade, associated the VM with the "default" subnet, and specifically removed the Network Security Group from the VM (leaving it on the subnet - just making sure it's not explicitly attached to the VM)
3. Tested HTTP access to the VM - traffic rejected
4. Tested HTTP access to the App Service - traffic still permitted
5. Changed the Network Security Group rule to allow
6. Tested HTTP access to the VM and traffic permitted

How do I get the App Service to use the Network Security Group the way the Virtual Machine does? Am I missing somewhere how to configure the subnet on the App Service? Is there another way to associate the NSG with the App Service?

I don't have budget/need to build an ASE. All I need to do is put a firewall in front of my App Service to block out the ports I'm not wanting to see used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do the impossible. Remember that Web Apps in App Service have to VPN into the VNET, there's nothing sitting between the internet and **80/TCP**, **443/TCP** in multi-tenant App Service that you have control of.

`Client ---> 80/TCP Frontend layer ---> 80/TCP Web App ---> Point-to-site VPN ---> VNET ---> NSG_associated_with_subnet`

So, no go.

See if [`<ipSecurity>`](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) works for your use case (my other answer here provides a quick sample - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808091/4148708). Else you either need an App Service Environment (ASE) or an Internal Load Balancer App Service Environment (ILB ASE).

They both directly sit in a Subnet in the VNET, so you can control traffic with NSGs.

Comment: I guess that since it

Comment: I guess that since it is PaaS, part of the platform is me trusting that the Azure team has properly configured the outward facing firewall. I've never deployed a web app before where I **didn't** have control/responsibility for putting up the firewall. I just assumed I was responsible for it here too.

I'll use the <ipSecurity> mechanism to redirect traffic from 80 to 443, and to whitelist admin subdirectories. And cross my fingers that the Azure team has secured the platform.

Comment: Rewrite rules for 80-> 443. Search for Force HTTPS here http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/   State your fear. What are the attack vectors you have in mind and can be addresses with firewall rules?

Comment: I had port scanned the App Service and thought there were a few ports that showed as open. Mostly it's just old habit of "don't put a non-locked down machine out on the cloud". If Azure takes care of that, I'll be ok.

I came across this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/ which seems to hint that you can hook up an app service to a vnet (presumably with NSG rules).Their example would need config to open up to the public internet - but looks doable. From what I've learned from you, the PaaS is already secured, so this is not needed