# Azure Web App DMZ

Tags: security, azure, azure-web-app-service, dmz

I will be hosting a web application using a Web App Service that stores data to a database using SQL Database Service in Azure. I do not need access to the server and I do not need a virtual machine, I want to keep my configuration as a (Paas) Platform as a service. My question is: how do I setup a DMZ in azure to protect the web app? This web app will be available to the public and there will be an admin section where the admins can update/add data.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about source IP security you could use `<ipSecurity>` in your web.config - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805769/how-to-check-azure-network-security-group-outbound-ip-allowed-or-not/38808091#38808091  Since this is a Layer-7 security feature, both good and evil HTTP requests will still reach your deployment. Take a look at ASE or ILB ASE if you're looking for Layer-3 firewalling.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you cannot install SQL Server in an App Service / web app. You need to install it in a VM or use the SQL Database service (which is its own separate DBaaS).

Comment: Also, you *can* access your Web App's environment, via kudu, easily - see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26385007/272109).

Comment: @DavidMakogon - I meant that I am using SQL Database Service to store data from Web App. Also I don't want access to remote control any server. I just want to see how to configure a DMZ using a Platform as a Service (Which is what WebApp service provides). I have a DMZ setup in amazon aws using Virtual machines. in Azure I dont need virtual machines so I was wondering how you do it.

Answer (score 1):

1.Please have a try to create [NSGs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/) to control inbound and outbound access to network interfaces (NICs) and subnets.

• Create a Network Security Group and [virtual network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-vnet-arm-pportal/) then config  it follow the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal/#associate-the-nsg-to-the-frontend-subnet)

• Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network
detail info please refer to the  [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)

• If you want to get more info about VET, please refer to [Azure Virtual network](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-overview/)

2.You also can have a try to use ASE and there are some ASE related

[Introduction to App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-app-service-environment/)

[Configuring a Web Application Firewall (WAF) for App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/zh-cn/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-web-application-firewall/)

[How to Control Inbound Traffic to an App Service Environment](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic/)